# AngularJS - Lazy loading same file names

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I am lazing loading my JS files in my SPA AngularJS app. The problem however is that as I navigate through different pages, the files are not un-loaded.

So say in `page1` I load a file called `/page1/myService.js` and then in `page2` I want to include `/page2/myService.js`. These two are two different files, but have the same name, and are both called `app.services('myService')`.

This causes a problem because both files with the same name are loaded! Is there a way to overcome this, other than making sure each file has a different name?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to lazy load your JS files?

Comment: since angularjs doesnt support lazyloading modules it would make sense to tell us what lib you are using exactly.

Comment: I am using RequireJS to lazy load m files